# Use function return value in string in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, flutter-text

I want to use the return value of a function, which is a string, with a string inside a Text Widget.
This is my code, task is an object of a class. It contains the date attribute.

```
Text(
   'Due to $getCurrentDate(task.date)',
    style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
    color: Colors.grey,
    ),
```

Used function

```
String getCurrentDate(DateTime date) {
  var currentDate = date.toString();

  var dateParse = DateTime.parse(currentDate);

  var formattedDate = "${dateParse.day}.${dateParse.month}.${dateParse.year}";

  return formattedDate;
}
```

When I use the code like this, which is what I want to achieve, it displays "Due to Closure:(DateTime) => String from Function 'getCurrentDate':static. (task.date)",

When I use a Text Widget like this, the date is displayed properly. e.g this is displayed "11.2.2023"

```
Text(
   getCurrentDate(task.date),
    style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
    color: Colors.grey,
    ),
```

But I want to achieve that it displays "Due to 11.2.2023"

Comment: interpolation was missing `'Due to ${getCurrentDate(task.date)}'`.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure, why I couldn't find this easy answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
'Due to ${getCurrentDate(task.date)}'
```

instead of

```
'Due to $getCurrentDate(task.date)'
```